# "Burnt-corked", what does it mean?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "burnt-corked" mean? Fahrenheit 451

> He knew that when he returned to the firehouse, he might wink at himself, a minstrel man, **burnt-corked**, in the mirror.

Comment: Did you check a dictionary? Burnt cork is what minstrels used to use to 'black up'.

Comment: I think without specific cultural understanding the line "minstrels used to use to 'black up'." is hard to understand.

Comment: @Astralbee Wiktionary has just about everything – but it does not have either "burnt-corked" or "burnt-cork"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is returning from a fire, and his face is blackened by soot from the fire.

"Minstrel" refers to the former entertainment of white performers painting their face black (for example using burnt cork as facepaint) and performing songs, in a caricature of black and African-American.  (See the Wikipedia article on [Minstrel show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minstrel_show) and [Blackface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackface).

So "burnt cork" is literal. It means a cork (such as could be used in a wine bottle) that has been partially burnt and blackened, and is used to create the "blackface".